# Cannot Define Type on 'this.$attrs' on Vue.js Component of Quasar App

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, ghost-blog, quasar

I really need help with this and have been stuck for days. (It's also my first question so don't roast me.)

I've been trying to build my Quasar app, but all my TypeScript errors scream about Unsafe (assignment |member access | call) on an 'any' value I've narrowed it down to the fact that the this.$attrs that I use to pass the URL into my component has a type: any, but I have no idea how to set a type on the $attrs attribute and haven't found anything about how to do that. If someone could help that'd be amazing.

Basically, what my app is trying to do is grab the slug attribute, and based on that it'll look up the appropriate page in my props. My props are populated with posts from the Ghost Blog API.

Here's an example block of where my errors are:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
import GhostModule from '../store';
import { PostOrPage, PostsOrPages } from '@tryghost/content-api';

export interface WhyPageState {
  page: PostOrPage;
  slug: PostOrPage['slug'];
}
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $attrs: {
      slug: string
    }
  }
}

export default {
  name: 'Page',

  created() {
    this.slug = this.$attrs.slug; // unsafe assignment of an any value
  },
  computed: mapState({
    page(state: typeof GhostModule) {
      const result: PostsOrPages = state?.GhostModule?.pages.filter(
        page => page.slug === this.slug // Unsafe member access on any value, Unsafe member access .slug on an any value
      );
      return result[0]; // Unsafe return of an any typed value, Unsafe member access[0] on an any value
    }
  })
};
```

If anyone has a solution on how to define types to $attrs or another solution entirely on how to populate ghost page data dynamically, it'd be appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `this` is not what you think it is, you're not using `Vue.extend()` or `vue-class-component`, so I'm unsure how you think `this` will refer to a Vue instance, hence `$attrs` not being typeable

Comment: Your type definition is `this.$attrs.slug` but you use `this.slug`

Comment: @Eldar I don't know where to set the definition for `this.$attrs` and I can't set it on the initial evaluation, that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy so I have to use `Vue.extend()` or `vue-class-component` to be able to set types for `this.$attrs`? I'm not fully aware of the difference between using `Vue.extend()` and just the typical export.